# Redux + Persist with tab state sync and disabling serializableCheck

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I use redux toolkit + redux-persist with *state sync across tabs*, everything works fine, config looks like this:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: [
      createStateSyncMiddleware({
        blacklist: ['persist/PERSIST', 'persist/REHYDRATE'],
      }),
    ],

  });
```

But for now I have to store some non serializable data and by default catch an error in my console (that's also expected, despite of console warnings all works fine)

**So my goal is to turn off serializableCheck and still use existing middleware (createStateSyncMiddleware).**

I tried to combine middleware :

```
const config = {
  blacklist: ['persist/PERSIST', 'persist/REHYDRATE'],
};
const synckStateMiddleware = [createStateSyncMiddleware(config)];

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      immutableCheck: false,
      serializableCheck: false,
    }).concat(synckStateMiddleware),
});
```

**Result: state sync works fine, but non-serialise warning still exist**

When I use this code (delete concat middleware with sync state):

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      immutableCheck: false,
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});
```

**Result: no warnings, but state sync is broken, of course.**